# Return to the previous page with inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Really unsure about the title question. Feel free to suggest. :)

Hi guys! I created a very simple code, that would represent my web.

Here is my home page:

```
<html>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function getPage(linkPage,variables,divName){
    $.get(linkPage + "?" + variables,function(data){$(divName).html(data);});
                }

    function show(){
              //functionName("path","data","idName");
               getPage("AjaxPages/hi.php","","#container");
            }
    </script>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
          First Name<input type="text" />
        <input type="button" value="next" onClick="show();"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, it ask for information, Name for example. When the button NEXT is click it will call a javascript function that will call a certain page or the NEXT PAGE that will load on the div with the Id Container.

**NEXT PAGE**

On the next page, it will then ask another question, like Last Name for example. But then, I want to go back to the previous page to make same changes.

HERE is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function show(){
            ajaxgetdata("index.php","","#container1");
    }
</script>
<div id="container">
Last Name<input type="text" />
what to make changes on the previous page?<input type="button" value="back" onClick="show();"/>
</div>
```

When button back is clicked, it will just call the previous page, but will not include the text that you input on the textbox.

I know that it happens because it just call the page..

Is there a way? that when back button is clicked, it will reload the previous page, with all the contents/inputs.

:) :( :'( :/ :|

Comment: You need to preserve the form data in one way or another. What have you tried?

Comment: Why make a different page? this could be easily done with a small slider

Comment: No. not yet @pmandell. How will I do that?

Comment: @Spokey I want to see just the one page at the time.. can you explain in depth the small slider?

Comment: @QKWS I was referring to a step by step form, something like http://wbotelhos.com/stepy

Comment: @Spokey, actually, that's what I'm trying to do, a step by step form. will check on this.

Comment: @QKWS, If its a step by step form, why dont you just do it client side? i mean by hidding and showing some divs, but always in the same URL, and use hashtags to handle the browse history (back button)? something like www.foo.com/bar#step1, www.foo.com/bar#step2, www.foo.com/bar#step3, that way, with javascript you can fill the form whenever you have a specific hashtag

Comment: @Spokey Thanks for link! Will try it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

- Don't load any additional pages. Do everything with AJAX.
- If you don't want, some server-side script may help :D

Comment: Everything will be on one page?

Comment: @QKWS yeah, I think that will be better. Smoother on the client side, less code on the server side, one PHP script file for handling one task.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use HTML5 in your site, you can take a look at the History API which can handle navigation and fires a "popstate" event, to which you can pass data.

There's a good example here:

http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

You could do something like this:

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
    if(!e.state || !e.state.firstName) {
        return;
    }

    document.getElementById('firstName').value = e.state.firstName;
});
```

That even will trigger everytime you go back or forward, and you could just organize some function or array with the information you need.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for this. But it is not only the FirstName, that is just an example. It going to be alot of inputs.

Comment: Easy, just use arrays :) and store all the inputs you want, or literal objects (dont use associative arrays) to send all the data all the time, at lease your planing on sending like a wikipedia of data. You can even loop the form and store all the values, on blur event of fields, to have an automated data mining process.

Comment: Or, if data is not that important, you can try sending data via get instead of post, and reading it again, but i dont recommend this, there's a lot of injection risks.